# Article a or the in the following sentence

Tags: grammar, articles

I would like to ask which article is suitable in the following sentences:

> 1) He fabricated a/the story that he left behind his wallet in a taxi and couldn’t contact the driver.

Comment: Either would be fine inn your exact context, and they'd mean *exactly* the same thing. If the story that he made up went on to become particularly well-known (perhaps, *It was him who fabricated the story that the Moon was made of green cheese*) you'd pretty much *have* to use the definite article, but that's a slightly different context.

Comment: I doubt many people would notice (and think it was "unusual") if you used ***the*** in your exact context, but in practice native speakers would be far more likely to use ***a*** there. On the other hand, unquestionably highly-respected writers will have used ***the*** sometimes - even if the specific story involved had no relevance outside the immediate context (and perhaps was never even referenced *there* outside of the containing sentence). So you really can decide for yourself which form you want to use here - whatever you choose, it won't be "wrong".

Comment: Thank you for your clear and good explanation. I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

The distinction is subtle but I think one would use the definite article in a case where they have a definite version of a story in mind that they want to emphasize - perhaps a version they heard the person use before, or read about or knew about.  If there is no specific version in mind, or no intention to emphasize that version, then one would use the indefinite article. I think confusion arises because the level of emphasis may be slight or ambiguous - for example the speaker might know of a specific version, but in fact the details of that version are not really significanct compared to the fact that it exists or has been used.

Comment: Thank you for your clear and good explanation. I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

Is the reader expected to be able to answer the question "*which story*?"

Does the question "*which story?*" matter?

- The answer to this question is *yes* if there is previous conversation/sentences mentioning the story, and the speaker/writer is talking about the same story.
- The answer to this question is also *yes* if the speaker/writer expects the listener/reader to *know* about the story from context or shared experience.

  - Without knowledge of previous conversation/sentences or shared experiences between speaker/writer and listener/reader, you won't be able to determine this and can only guess.

If yes, *the* is used.

If no, *a* is used.